# How can I comment in a answer which the owner doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: support

My question is very simple, I'm trying to understand this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/31272/42912) and I would like to ask to the answerer more details how to prove it and what he means by reduce module $g$, the problem is the user is not here at MSE anymore, what should I do? can I ask a new question asking about this answer? What is the standard procedure in this case?

I'm a little confused

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply posting a new question asking for clarification of a particular answer (with a detailed explanation what you don't understand). See this older discussion: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer